# Looping over an object that is within a another object

Tags: html, reactjs

So I was working on this name card generator app. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users is the source of my database. 
Any idea how to loop through the **address** part? My code so far.

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import Namecard from './namecard'

    function App() {
      const [identis, setIdenti]=useState([]);

      useEffect(()=>{
        getIdenti()
      },[]
      );

      const getIdenti = async()=>{
      const acquired = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      const data = await acquired.json()
      setIdenti(data)
      }

      return (
        <div>
          {identis.map(identi=>(
            <Namecard 
            name={identi.name}
            email={identi.email}
            address={identi.address}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        )}

    export default App
```

Comment: Build an address component, pass the data as props.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're going for something along these lines. Just to at least answer the question - here is how you would loop through the address. And I'm guessing you're trying to build up a readable string or something...

```js
var users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    }
  }
];

var addressStr = '';
for (var user of users) {
  addressStr = '';
  for (var key of Object.keys(user.address)) {
    key !== 'geo' && (addressStr += user.address[key] + ' ');
  }
  console.log(addressStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of looping through address part, just build a separate Address component.

```
const Address = ({ street, suite, ... }) => <h1>Street: {street}</h1>

const Namecard = ({ name, ..., children }) => <div> Name: {name} <div>{children}</div></div> // where children is the Address component

<Namecard 
  name={identi.name}
  email={identi.email}
>
  <Address {...identi.address} />
</Namecard>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do another component unless I think I'll reuse it - I suppose you might with an address so not throwing stones but OP asked for a loop so I figure they know their use-case and didn't want another component. Good to have options I guess.

Comment: Yeah, just giving an option on how OP can approach the issue :)

Comment: hey albert, can you give me a complete set of code? I am having some troubles with the syntax. thanks!